# Inequality $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+n^2}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+1}$

Tags: inequality, summation, riemann-sum

From this question [How do you calculate this limit? $\lim_{n\to\infty}( \frac{1^2}{n^3+1^2} + \frac{2^2}{n^3+2^2} ... + \frac{n^2}{n^3+n^2})=?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043717/how-do-you-calculate-this-limit-lim-n-to-infty-frac12n312-frac)

I have not understood the reason of the @xpaul's answer for the $(1)$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+n^2}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^3+1} \tag 1$$

Comment: Since $k\geq 1$, $n^3+k^2\geq n^3+1$, so $\frac1{n^3+k^2}\leq\frac1{n^3+1}$; multiply this by $k^2$ to get $\frac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}\leq\frac{k^2}{n^3+1}$, and then just sum termwise to get the latter inequality. The first one works the same way, using $k\leq n$ rather than $k\geq 1$.

Comment: answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734039/find-a-limit-using-riemann-sums  is pretty good

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Please, can you convert you comment in an answer? I like vote up :-)

Comment: @WillJagy Hi and grazieeeee for your comment/link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sum ranges from $k=1$ to $k=n$, we have $k\geq 1$ and $k\leq n$; thus $n^2\geq k^2\geq 1$. Translate by $n^3$ to get $n^3+n^2\geq n^3+k^2\geq n^3+1$, then invert (changing the direction of the inequalities) to get $\dfrac1{n^3+n^2}\leq \dfrac1{n^3+k^2}\leq \dfrac1{n^3+1}$. Multiply by $k^2$ to get $\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+n^2}\leq\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+k^2}\leq\dfrac{k^2}{n^3+1}$, and then just sum termwise over $k$.

Comment: Perfect...and very nice your answers :-)